# Trying to add looped string to empty dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate links using a for loop and trying to add them to my empty dataframe like the example below:

```
linkdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Link'])


for i in range(1,10):
  l = 'https://google.com/assets/' + str(i)
  linkdf = linkdf.append(l)
```

but I am getting errors like below:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only
> Series and DataFrame objs are valid

is there a way to add this to the empty dataframe with header already provided.

want result like below:

```
        Link
0.  https://google.com/assets/1
1   https://google.com/assets/2
2.  https://google.com/assets/3
```

Appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: Replace your append statement by : linkdf.loc[len(linkdf)] = [l]

Comment: Is there a reason why you really want to use a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create list and then pass to `DataFrame` like:

```
L = ['https://google.com/assets/' + str(i) for i in range(1,10)]
linkdf = pd.DataFrame(L,  columns=['Link'])
```

Your solution:

```
L = []
for i in range(1,10):
  l = 'https://google.com/assets/' + str(i)
  L.append(l)


print (L)
['https://google.com/assets/1', 'https://google.com/assets/2', 
 'https://google.com/assets/3', 'https://google.com/assets/4',  
 'https://google.com/assets/5', 'https://google.com/assets/6', 
 'https://google.com/assets/7', 'https://google.com/assets/8', 
 'https://google.com/assets/9']
```

---

```
linkdf = pd.DataFrame(L,  columns=['Link'])
print (linkdf)
                          Link
0  https://google.com/assets/1
1  https://google.com/assets/2
2  https://google.com/assets/3
3  https://google.com/assets/4
4  https://google.com/assets/5
5  https://google.com/assets/6
6  https://google.com/assets/7
7  https://google.com/assets/8
8  https://google.com/assets/9
```

---

If really need add data to empty DataFrame (it is slow):

```
linkdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Link'])

for i in range(1,10):
  l = 'https://google.com/assets/' + str(i)
  linkdf = linkdf.append({'Link':l}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: hi jezrael thank you for getting back i want to use your second solution but got this error"TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments"

Comment: @Zac - There is used `L.append(l)` instead `linkdf = linkdf.append` ?

Comment: @Zac - What is `print (L)` ? It is list?

Answer (score 1):

Or why not just `np.char.add`:

```
linkdf['Link'] = np.char.add('https://google.com/assets/', np.arange(1, 10).astype(str))
```

---

```
>>> linkdf
                          Link
0  https://google.com/assets/1
1  https://google.com/assets/2
2  https://google.com/assets/3
3  https://google.com/assets/4
4  https://google.com/assets/5
5  https://google.com/assets/6
6  https://google.com/assets/7
7  https://google.com/assets/8
8  https://google.com/assets/9
>>>
```

Comment: sorry u12-forward this might not be the solution i am looking for but thank you for giving time

Comment: @Zac Hmmm, why?

Comment: this is small part issue of my large code and changing it with your solution will have to change my whole code thank you again.